# Firebase authentication is not working while the background data is restricted

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

Currently I am working on an android app which is based on firebase firestore. I am using firebase auth 15.0.0 for login.
But login doesn't work if background data is restricted. It returns "
a network error (such as timeout interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred". It specially happens on SAMSUNG phones. help me please! I want it to work after background data is restricted also.

Comment: What do you mean by "Background data is restricted" ?

Comment: It  is an option in many phones setting. That is to limit the cellular data usage. If that option is 'on ',login doesn't work. It returns a network error.

Comment: So isn't it doing what is expected?? When you restrict the data, it will return `Network` error and how can you login to any app using FirebaseAuth or anything when there is no network at all.

Comment: oh no! there is a network. it is just the background data restricted, not the fore-ground

Answer (score 0):

Background data is now very restrictive. Some phone can set it in the APP's settings, like my Xiaomi. But that is very manual and can't be a real solution.

Proper way is to use Firebase Cloud Messaging, which keeps a so-called weak-socket-connection. This way saves battery.

The cloud messaging can contain message < 2k, if your message is above that limit, you can create a notification to notify user to wake up your application, and use fore-ground data.