# Firebase auth not working if mobile background data is restricted on my device

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I am building an android app and trying to implement firebase auth system.
Right now, it doesn't work if my background data is restricted.

I get this error

> Firebase Authentication FirebaseNetworkException: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred

It only works when I dont restrict background data.

I am testing on Samsung phone s7 running on 6.0

I checked this question [Firebase authentication is not working while the background data is restricted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54661595/firebase-authentication-is-not-working-while-the-background-data-is-restricted) 
but no satisfying answer.

Questions:

1. How do I get the auth system to work even if background data is restricted?
2. Does it mean when I deploy my app on the playstore, users who restricted background data on their devices would not be able to use my app? If yes, then I most likely wont be using the firebase authentication.

Comment: Is there a reason that answer you linked wasn't satisfactory enough?

Comment: That answer was about cloud messaging, Question was about firebase auth.

Comment: Please can anyone clarify for me and answer??